# MyEclipse 6.0 crashes on Window7

Tags: windows-7, workspace, myeclipse

When I open MyEclipse version 6.0 on Window 7 and select workspace
then its loading and crashes just when loading complete

Any idea why it happen..where I am wrong..

**-Amit Battan**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was solved by replacing workspace folder

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a conflict between 32-bit MyEclipse and 64-bit jvm...